# Installing Orchard 1.0 CMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, hosting, orchardcms

I'v Installed Orchard 1.0 CMS , so I'v downloaded Orchard.Web.1.0.20.zip , then I copy all files from this folder and put them into my server by FTP, all files has been successfull sended.
When I go to my site I have Error, but I don't know how to solve them and why I have error?
I only copy files, IMHO it should be OK.

link to my page: http://konradkubacki.studentlive.pl/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your website is running in .NET 4 Integrated mode.

Try adding the

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

section to your system.web section in *Web.config* file to show more detailed information. Please post it here so I'd be able to provide more detailed solution. 
*Remember to turn showing the errors to the world **off** after that (mode="On"):)*

[EDIT] The detailed error info you provided shows that there is a **permission issue** with accessing the Dependencies folder. Just grant the app user account (**IUSR_machinename** by default) permissions to access that folder - I answered a [similar question](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/245882) on Orchard Codeplex site a while ago. But you have to have access to the server to do that.

*You can also try creating that folder (App_Data/Dependencies) by hand after uploading Orchard, so appropriate permissions would be granted to the user under which your hosting account runs.*

HTH

Comment: @PeterSmith  changed the web.config file as You adviced me link to changed web.config http://wklej.org/id/502931/

There are other errors. link to page: http://konradkubacki.studentlive.pl/

Comment: @PeterSmith I'v made folder Depencies in APP_data and i'v changed permission for all folders with subfolders , now I have error Like this: Access to the path 'D:\inetpub\hosting\student\konradkubacki.studentlive.pl\App_Data\Dependencies\Joel.Net.Akismet.dll' is denied.

Comment: @Konrad Weird... Try setting the permissions for the whole App_Data folder with subfolders. Also check the account under which the app runs (maybe it's different from the default?).

Comment: @PeterSmith the appdata folder has 755 permission with subfolders.